# laravel codeigniter password

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

I have a query regarding project migrate from CodeIgniter to Laravel. I want to create a web API using the laravel framework.

Existing project was made in the CodeIgniter framework.

Laravel has it's own hash way of a password. How can I manage users password from CodeIgniter? How can I allow to login with a current password?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to identify first what type of encrypt is the Codeigniter using on the password field and then you have to decrypt or validate the password on Laravel. I had the reverse problem and on codeigniter I had to use a library ('encrypt') in order to validate the Hash the Laravel uses.